# Why does drawing anything on a JS canvas in a for loop cause the page to load endlessly?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is the simpelest I code I could come up with to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="7" height="7"></canvas>
        
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            
            for (i = 1; i < 2; i+2){
                context.fillRect(1,i,5,1);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As soon I try to do anything on a canvas in a for loop, the page loads endlessly and my pc starts making lots of noise. What's going wrong, and how can I fix it?

**Solution**

Beginner mistake: `i+2` should be `i+=2`. (Also `i < 2` doesn't make sense if the increment is 2.)

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < 2; i+2){` is an infinite loop. You want `for (let i = 1; i < 2; i+=2){`

Comment: i see you putting the solution from your accepted answer there, that is not necessary at all btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in your increment expression. Replace `i+2` with `i+=2` and it should work just fine.

Comment: [Dissuade answers to simple typos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260104/dissuade-answers-to-simple-typos)

Comment: @jabaa Ah, okay. Sorry, I wasn't aware of this practice. I'll be sure to keep it in mind.